# how to remove virtue mart components from back end for non super users in joomla

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

i Want to know that how to remove virtue mart components from back end for non super users in joomla.. thanks in advance

Comment: What version of Joomla?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joomla ACLs allows this.

Go to virtuemart component options -> there should be a permissions/security tab, remove access from administrators there.

**If it's not there, just add this to the modules' config and it should be enough to show it and make it work:

```
<fieldset
    name="permissions"
    label="JCONFIG_PERMISSIONS_LABEL"
    description="JCONFIG_PERMISSIONS_DESC"
    >

    <field
        name="rules"
        type="rules"
        label="JCONFIG_PERMISSIONS_LABEL"
        filter="rules"
        validate="rules"
        component="com_virtuemart"
        section="component">
        <action
            name="core.admin"
            title="JAction_Admin"
            description="JACTION_ADMIN_COMPONENT_DESC" />
        <action
            name="core.manage"
            title="JAction_Manage"
            description="JACTION_MANAGE_COMPONENT_DESC" />
    </field>
</fieldset>
```